# Count joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables `tblFuneralHomes` and `tblFuneralTransactions`. One table may has many transactions. I need to return user's `funeralHomes` and count transactions, but if funeralHomes has not transactions, it's not returned in result.

```
Select tfh.funeral_home_guid, tfh.funeral_home_name, tfh.reference_key, count(tft.id) as counts from tblFuneralHomes tfh
inner join tblFuneralTransactions tft on tft.funeral_home_guid = tfh.funeral_home_guid where (tft.canceled=0 and tft.completed=0)
and tfh.funeral_home_guid in (select funeral_home_guid 
from tblDirectorHomes
where director_id = '1789a3ae-95e5-4719-ac09-bd1ada01dd5b') 
group by tfh.funeral_home_guid, tfh.funeral_home_name, tfh.reference_key
```

This is the result without join [image]

I know what current user has 3 `funeralHomes`.

But when I join transactions and count that, one of those homes hasn't transactions and it not displayed.

[image]

Comment: Sample data and expected output will be more helpful.

Comment: @SurajKumar one moment

Comment: Left outer join, not inner join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of a `INNER JOIN` so all records of `tblFuneralHomes` are taken:

```
SELECT tfh.funeral_home_guid, tfh.funeral_home_name, tfh.reference_key, COUNT(tft.id) AS counts 
FROM tblFuneralHomes tfh LEFT JOIN tblFuneralTransactions tft ON tft.funeral_home_guid = tfh.funeral_home_guid 
WHERE (tft.funeral_home_guid IS NULL OR (tft.canceled = 0 AND tft.completed = 0))
    AND tfh.funeral_home_guid IN (
        SELECT funeral_home_guid 
        FROM tblDirectorHomes
        WHERE director_id = '1789a3ae-95e5-4719-ac09-bd1ada01dd5b'
    )
GROUP BY tfh.funeral_home_guid, tfh.funeral_home_name, tfh.reference_key
```

You are using columns of `tblFuneralTransactions` on the `WHERE` conditions. In case a record of `tblFuneralHomes` has no `tblFuneralTransactions` all column values of the (not available) `tblFuneralTransactions` record are `NULL`. So the following condition is false: `tft.canceled = 0 AND tft.completed = 0`.

To include all records of `tblFuneralHomes` you need to allow the columns of `tblFuneralTransactions` to be `NULL`. So you have to replace this condition

```
(tft.canceled = 0 AND tft.completed = 0)
```

to the following

```
(tft.funeral_home_guid IS NULL OR (tft.canceled = 0 AND tft.completed = 0))
```

Comment: I've tried LEFT JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN but got the same result

Comment: see the update (added `tft.funeral_home_guid IS NULL` part). Try the whole query again.

Comment: I don't know why, but still got not all homes. If I remove 

_where (tft.completed = 0 and tft.canceled = 0)_
 I get all homes with counts.

Comment: you need to allow the NULL values - see the explanation

Comment: Done. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest following query (little modification of your query):

```
Select tfh.funeral_home_guid, 
       tfh.funeral_home_name, 
       tfh.reference_key, 
       sum(case when tft.id is null then 0 else 1 end) as counts 
from tblFuneralHomes tfh
left join tblFuneralTransactions tft on tft.funeral_home_guid = tfh.funeral_home_guid 
where (tft.canceled=0 and tft.completed=0)
  and tfh.funeral_home_guid in (select funeral_home_guid 
                                from tblDirectorHomes
                                where director_id = '1789a3ae-95e5-4719-ac09-bd1ada01dd5b') 
group by tfh.funeral_home_guid, tfh.funeral_home_name, tfh.reference_key
```

I switched to `left join`, so not matched funeral homes will still be included in resultset. More over, I handled correpsonding `nul` values from other tables: when it's null then column should be 0, else 1. Then it's enough to sum those values.